# Kusto: How to find missing values from a list

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am trying to generate a list of values that are missing from a set list of values.I have a query like below:

```
    let fcu = todynamic(pack_array("Alarm",
        "State",
        "Zone",
        "Air",
        "Temp Sp",
        "Fan",
        "Zone Air"));
    let ac = all
    | join kind=inner (AT) on  $left.SourceId == $right.Id
    | summarize Models=todynamic(make_list(Name2)) by Id
    | extend   MissingValues =     
    array_iff(dynamic([false,false,false,false,false,false,false]), fcu, Models);
```

This gives me the MissingValues as below, with null values that are missing in Models. How do I get the list of values that are missing?

```
"MissingValues": [
"Alarm",
    "State",
    "Zone",
    "Air",
    "Temp Sp",
    null,
    null
],
```

Comment: Please add data sample + required results in text/datatable format

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to use [`set_difference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/setdifferencefunction) in order to get the set of all distinct values that are in the first array ("expected") but aren't in other array ("actual")